# MATLAB, what is the best way to trace a boarder in a matrix that is changing each step?

Tags: matlab, matrix, iteration, gradient, average

I want to calculate the average slope or gradient at each iteration in such a matrix.

```
a=[ 10 9 8 7 6 5 5;
9  9 8 7 8 5 5; 
8  8 7 7 5 5 5; 
7  7 7 6 5 5 5;
6  6 6.6 5 5 5 5;
6  6 6.1 5 5 5 5;
6.3  5 5 5 5 5 5]
```

Where I am wanting to find the slope or gradient between the a(1,1) position during each step and at each point that boarders a value of 5. Each iteration the position of the 5's changes and so do the other values.

After doing so I will then average the slope. I haven't encountered a problem like this yet and I could not find a Matlab command to simplify.

Comment: Your question is a little bit hazy. Can you provide more detail about what you want to do exactly?

Comment: I think some detail on my project will make it clear. The matrix is a value of elevations. And the program simulates a river delta radially growing. So each matrix looks roughly like that of a quadrant of a circle. I want to take the slope from the origin to each cell along the edge of the delta. The edge of delta meets the sea level which is 5 in this case. After taking the slope to each point on the edge of the delta I want to average this slope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you must find out which the coast elements are. From your definition, an element is  a coast element if it border (from the right) with a 5. If the sea level is 5, and is the lowest possible value i.e. no element goes beyond sea level, then you must first find all the land elements as,

```
land=a>5;
```

This returns,

```
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Now, the coast elements are 1s that are followed by a 0. Take the column difference of the land matrix,

```
coastTmp=diff(land,1,2);
```

returning,

```
ans =

     0     0     0     0    -1     0
     0     0     0     0    -1     0
     0     0     0    -1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     0     0
     0     0    -1     0     0     0
     0     0    -1     0     0     0
    -1     0     0     0     0     0
```

and find the -1s,

```
coast=find(coastTmp==-1);
```

which are,

```
coast =

     7
    19
    20
    24
    25
    29
    30
```

From here it is easy. The gradient is  the difference of a(1,1) with all the coast elements, i.e.

```
slope=a(coast)-a(1,1);  % negative slope here
```

giving,

```
slope =

  -3.700000000000000
  -3.400000000000000
  -3.900000000000000
  -3.000000000000000
  -4.000000000000000
  -4.000000000000000
  -2.000000000000000
```

and of course the mean is,

```
mean(slope);
```

Comment: Wow thank you very much. I got about half way to what you did, that find function is very useful!

Comment: Np. Just spotted a typo. At the beginning its land=a>5; not land=a<5;. Anyway, you should know that this code works only if the coast element have a sea element **to their right**. In any other case, it will not detect them e.g. if the coast element is above or below a sea element. In such a case you should get trickier to calculate them.

Comment: There are numerous problems with the details in this answer (index values for `coastTmp` aren't valid for `a`, because the sizes are different, etc.), but the approach is good.

Comment: How are the index values not valid?

Comment: The index values are valid when I checked. This works well because now I can use ind2sub to find the row and column at each point and us the triangle identity to find distance as well to that cell.